# How do I fix USB Mic Static through a preamp?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, noise, preamp

I am trying to setup a semi-pro recording area for creating a podcast and I am quite new to audio recording.

I have a [KAM C3](http://kaminstruments.com/studio-mics.htm) (Bottom one on the site) Mic going into an [ART Tube MP - Project Series](http://www.artproaudio.com/products.asp?type=79&cat=1&id=115) with an XLR cable. From the Preamp I go through USB 1.1 into my computer, I'm getting a low buzzing/static that is present when I record through the mic.

I also have a [Razer Megalodon](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/DisplayCategoryProductListPage/categoryID.35096300) (USB) which gets the same static/buzzing so I am assuming that the static/buzzing is comming from either the USB port (Ive tried 3 different ports on my PC, but they are all in the same area because I heard it may be a grounding issue) or the computer itself.

Are there any other ways I could fix this, or maybe a sound card that I could buy that would eliminate this issue.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the preamp should take care of the noise frequently found in soundcard A/D converters. Try listening to your recording somewhere other than your computer to ensure the noise isn't happening on playback - maybe it's not an input problem at all, but rather an output problem.